# refresh num campo após submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, banco-de-dados, input, tabela-html

Estou fazendo uma tabela de preços de custo e venda onde o usuário vai poder alterar a margem que ele deseja. [image: Tabela com itens que precisam ter a margem alterada.]

Após inserir a margem do primeiro item, não importa o que eu faça, se eu clicar no botão update (verde) ao lado da margem, independente do valor que eu coloque no input, ele vai atualizar no banco com os valores do primeiro input. Parece que o JS só lê o primeiro input.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo está meu JS:

```
$('td a.atualizamargem').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).attr("title");
        var input = document.querySelector("#margem");
        var margem = input.value;
        // alert(margem);



        // $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../conexoes/atualizamargem.php",
            async: true,
            data: {
                id_preco: id,
                margem: margem
            }

        });

        location.reload();
        $(".margem")[0].reset();


    });
```

O sistema insere no banco, faz o reload da página, mas mesmo com reload, parece que não limpa o campo enviado.

Comment: Um id deve ser único na página. Ao fazer `var input = document.querySelector("#margem");` vai pegar sempre o primeiro que encontrar.

Comment: Sam, nesse caso eu teria que pegar o ID da linha, que é único? Pois como se trata de uma tabela que traz os campos do banco, serão muitas linhas

Comment: Poderiam informar porque tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta foram negativados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um id deve ser único na página. Ao fazer `var input = document.querySelector("#margem");` vai pegar sempre o primeiro elemento que tiver o id `#margem` que encontrar. Mas nem é esse o cerne da questão. É que um id deve ser único mesmo.

Em vez de usar id, altere para `class="margem"` e use:

```
var input = $(this).closest("tr").find(".margem");
var margem = input.val();
```

Explicação:

```
$(this)          ->  elemento que disparou o evento click
.closest("tr")   ->  busca o primeiro ancestral TR
.find(".margem") ->  procura no ancestral o elemento com a classe .margem
```

Assim ele vai procurar dentro da linha `TR` do mesmo elemento que disparou o evento click o elemento com a classe `.margem` (se estiver usando `table`).

Se o elemento já tiver `class`, basta adicionar na lista o `margem` e excluir o `id="margem"`, ex.:

```
<input class="bla form-control margem" name="algumacoisa">
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129563/discussion-on-answer-by-sam-refresh-num-campo-apos-submit)

Comment: Muito obrigado ! Vc é o cara! Resolveu em 30 seg o que estou demorando 2 dias